# PDF version downgrade to 1.4 - No SSH access

Tags: php, pdf, cpanel

I'm currently using mpdf to merge together a few pdf files the users uploaded. I found myself to face the issue of mpdf using the free version of FPDI which gives a `mPDF error: Unable to find xref table - Maybe a Problem with 'auto_detect_line_endings'` error when trying to operate on files whose PDF version is higher than 1.4.

I don't have ssh access but just CPanel, so I can't install GhostScript. Having to tell users to manually re-save and downgrade their own PDFs before uploading them surely isn't the way to go at it.

tl;dr Is there some way to downgrade PDFs to 1.4, using PHP, without ssh access/relying on an external server to convert?

Comment: you are in you own server or shared hosting ?

Comment: I'm on shared hosting

Comment: If you can not install additional software (such as Ghostscript) on the server, you will have to rely on the users to create PDF 1.4 documents. Keep in mind that you may have to completely reprocess higher version documents, which requires a good PDF interpreter and creator application. A possible line to follow might be finding an utility which creates PDF/X1-a.

Comment: The error message is from a very old version of FPDI. Are you using the latest verison of mPDF and FPDI?

Comment: i don't think that shared hosting giving their users the permission to install software in it's servers, you will have to ask them for upgrade this software to you

Comment: Tried to update to a new version, but to no avail. They do say on FPDI's website that the free version only supports up to PDF 1.4, in fact.